# Database Primary Keys and Validation

Tags: database, validation, database-design, primary-key

'ello, I'm a student in college, studying Computing. I'm currently doing my course work (which entails creating a database) and I was hoping if you could clear somethings up for me. Side-note: not programming specific.

1) Can you use strings as primary keys i.e MemberName?
2) Do primary keys need to have "ID" in their name?
3) If you were to use Names as primary keys, would you be able to use validation techniques to ensure that each name is unique?

I've currently done most of my coursework on the assumption that I can use names as primary keys and validation to ensure that they are unique, since an example database that we created prior to the coursework ran on the same principles. However, my teacher (a new teacher) is telling me that I need to re-do my work and I'm trying to find a way out of having to re-do everything, since I have consulted our learning resources and can't find any reasons to have to use integers for primary keys or any reasons for not being able to use validation.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot use strings as primary keys. They need to have a unique ID. Normally you can use auto int so you don't have to worry about it. There is no "validation" techniques, a query would likely fail.

Comment: I suspect your teacher insists on the core principles for database design which state that a key must not have a meaning other than the pure technical key value. A "name" would violate this constraint since it carries information other than mere record identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You CAN make a string column be a primary key, but as has already been pointed out, it is not wise. The value can change, invalidating the key for anything that references it, and usually requiring the data row to be deleted and reinserted with the new key. The storage of the key is also unlikely to be efficient. A 64-bit identifier (typical case) is going to use less space than any name longer than 8 ASCII characters. Any query that links to a primary key is going to do comparisons between keys, and those are going to be most efficient if they align to the hardware, which is almost certainly 64-bit.

2) Naming conventions can be very powerful, so including an indicator in a column name to show that it is a primary key is wise. I personally dislike using ID for this, because I've had too many databases that had an actual ID field (like Employee ID issued Y/N) and this causes confusion. I prefer PK_tablename as a primary key name (and FK_tablename for foreign keys that link to it), but including any standard in the name is definitely optional from a SQL point of view.

3) You can use validation techniques to ensure uniqueness before insertion, but this is yet another argument against using anything but meaningless numbers as keys. It is easy to overlook concurrency issues with keys. If two processes try to insert the same name at the same time, and each one checks for existence (uniqueness) first, you could have deadlocking or other racing conditions. Almost all databases provide a guarantee that the default key datatype (again, usually 64-bit) can be generated atomically. This lets you insert a row no matter what and be sure every row has a unique ID. If you wrap your validation into a transaction to force concurrent insertions of the same key to go in order, you could kill your performance or have other deadlocking issues.

Your professor is right. It's best to go with the default key datatype, even if you don't HAVE to.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some quick answers

1. You can use strings as primary keys, but it is usually a bad idea. Primary keys are usually indexed, and using an numeric value usually means your primary key is smaller in terms of bytes and therefore takes less storage when creating the index and performs faster during joins or as part of other indexes that may be created. It's also generally a bad idea to define a key on something that can change. If you define a key on `MemeberName` and a user wants to change it, then it becomes difficult to make that change due to other tables that may reference your MemberName primary key as a foreign key in that table.
2. The name of the column has no effect on whether it can be defined as a primary key. You can even define multiple columns as a primary key (called composite primary keys) so long as the collection of columns produce a unique record.
3. The database will give you an error trying to insert a duplicate primary key, but if using a string value that is based on data input, you'd probably be best served checking if it exists before inserting.

Comment: A very good answer. I'd like to add that using names as keys is a bad idea not only because they Will need to be changed as Jason W points out, but also because you Will have more than one "Jason" or "John Smith". primary keys must be unique and names of people will not be unique.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with using strings as keys if it makes sense to do so in a given situation. Irrespective of data type keys are required to be minimally unique identifiers. Aside from uniqueness and minimality, there are three other desirable characteristics you should keep in mind when choosing or designing your keys: Simplicity, Stability and Familiarity. In practice people do often find it simpler to remember and work with words and letters rather than just numbers and that is why alphanumeric identifiers are very common (e.g. car licence plates, airline flight numbers, seat reservation numbers, state and country codes, postal codes, email addresses). There are studies and annecdotal evidence to support the idea that alphanumeric keys are more usable than numbers alone. Also, alphanumeric identifiers can often be shorter than numeric ones.

In your case, if MemberName is a person's name then very possibly it isn't a practical choice of identifier because different people often have the same name. On the other hand there are circumstances in which a personal "name" does make sense as a key - for example a user's login name for a website. You need to decide these things based on what requirement you are trying to address.